# Returning objects constructed in lambda in transform

Tags: c++, object, lambda, return-value, transformation

The following function does something different than I want, which is to return the matches. If I call it on `vector<string>{"a b", "cd ef"}`, the output is

```
cd 
cd ef
```

instead of

```
a b
cd ef
```

Why?

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

void f(const vector<string>& v) {
  vector<smatch> P{};
  transform(begin(v), end(), back_inserter(P), [](auto s){
    auto m = *new smatch;
    regex_match(s, m, regex{"(\\S*) (\\S*) ?(.*)"});
    return m;
  });
  for (auto s: P) cout << s[0] << endl; // debug output
}
```

It's the same if I try without `new`: `smatch m{};`. Which I believe I shouldn't do, because then the `smatch` is allocated on the stack and invalidated when the lambda function returns. (I even tried `smatch m;`, but that should create an uninitialized variable. Oddly, it works with no runtime error, giving the same wrong result.) And the following doesn't even compile, giving an error I don't understand:

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

void f(const vector<string>& v) {
  vector<smatch> P{};
  transform(begin(v), end(), back_inserter(P), [](auto s){
    auto m = new smatch;
    regex_match(s, m, regex{"(\\S*) (\\S*) ?(.*)"});
    cout << (*m)[0] << endl;
    return m;
  });
  for (auto s: P) cout << (*s)[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Additionally: are the `{}` in `vector<smatch> P{};` and `smatch m{};` necessary? Am I right that otherwise the variables are uninitialized and might lead to runtime errors?

Comment: `vector<smatch> P{};` and `smatch m{};` are just same as `vector<smatch> P;` and `smatch m;` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [`std::match_results`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results):

> Because `std::match_results` holds `std::sub_matches`, each of which is a pair of iterators into the original character sequence that was matched, it's undefined behavior to examine `std::match_results` if the original character sequence was destroyed or iterators to it were invalidated for other reasons.

The parameter `s` of the lambda is passed by-value, it'll be destroyed when get out of the lambda. You can change it to pass-by-reference:

```
void f(const vector<string>& v) {
  vector<smatch> P;
  transform(begin(v), end(v), back_inserter(P), [](auto& s){
    //                                                 ^
    smatch m;
    regex_match(s, m, regex{"(\\S*) (\\S*) ?(.*)"});
    return m;
  });
  for (auto s: P) cout << s[0] << endl; // debug output
}
```

Comment: But won't `m` get automatic lifetime and its destructor called when lambda finishes executing?

Comment: @ByteEater Yes. But it'll be copied as the return value of the lambda and then copied into the vector `P`.

Comment: More precisely, will it be moved, not copied? `match_results`, of which `smatch` is a specialization, has a move constructor. Additionally (after you edited), I'd like to ask, for better understanding: will the constructor be called twice?

Comment: @ByteEater Yes, it'll be moved twice. One for the `return`, one for being `push_back`ed into the `vector`.